# Where is the "Style Library" folder in SharePoint Online?

Tags: site-collection, publishing-site, publishing, style-library

I have a site collection at the following location: **www.example.sharepoint.com/SiteCollection/**.

My understanding is that the Style Library should be located at **www.example.sharepoint.com/SiteCollection/Style%20Library/** however I cannot find it there.

I know publishing must be enabled for this folder to appear, but I do not know at what level. Currently, publishing is enabled at the site collection level. I do not know if it is enabled at the root level (**www.example.sharepoint.com**) as I don't have access to this area.

Should publishing be enabled at the root level in order to access the Style Library for this site collection? If yes, how can I tell if it is?

Comment: check if SharePoint Server Publishing feature is active on site level. Append '/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx' to your URL

Comment: @aveenav I already enabled it there. I need to know if it must be enabled at the root level. Basically, I need to know if I need to talk to the "big guys" and ask them to enable it because I don't have root access.

Comment: Nope, root you're referring to is a different site collection. Every site collection will have their own Style Library.

Comment: Try de-activating and then re-activate the Publishing feature on Site Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **two** Publishing features that need to be enabled, one at the site collection level and one at the web (aka site) level.

A key concept to understand here is that when you create a site collection, it has what is known as a "Root Web", which is the top site in the site collection.  Because it's the top site in the site collection, it has some special things which subsites don't have, but, at the same time, it has some things in common with subsites.

Do not confuse the "Root Web" of a site collection with a "root site" of a web application.

In your case, if your site collection has the URL

```
www.example.sharepoint.com/SiteCollection
```

then that is **also** the URL of the Root Web of your site collection.

The site at

```
www.example.sharepoint.com
```

is known as a "root site" also because it is at the root of your web application.

So, getting back to your site collection, if you go to

```
www.example.sharepoint.com/SiteCollection
```

and go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site Collection Features, you can enable a feature called "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure".  This is the feature you need to enable at the **site collection** level (hence "Site Collection Features").

Now, if you go back to the Site Settings page, under Site Actions you will see "Manage site features".  If you click on that link, you will see a completely different set of features.  The one you want to activate there is "SharePoint Server Publishing". *That* feature is the one that enables Publishing for the **Root Web** of your Site Collection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So, to enable "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" at the site collection level, I'll have to talk to the site collection administrator, correct? I don't see that option under my site settings page.

Comment: Yes, exactly, you will need a Site Collection Admin to enable the site collection feature.

Answer (score 2):

Style Library is located on the top level publishing web site. So you need to enable the publishing feature on the root site as well.